# .NET Core Custom Authorize Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing a new application in MVC .NET Core 2 but I have to use the existing Authentication and Authorization that's used in another application developed in MVC5. It calls a webservice with the current users details to get a list of the groups and roles the user is in, this is done in the GetUserRoles method. From googling it looks like this is done differently now compared to MVC 5. Could anyone help me implement this so I can use it like so:

```
 [BasicAuthorisation(Roles = "SpecificUser")]
```

Here is a snippet of the filter that I'm trying to implement in .NET Core:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class BasicAuthorisation : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    MemoryCache mc = MemoryCache.Default;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _principal;
    private string _applicationName = "";

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool skipAuthorisation = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
            || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

        _principal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (_principal.Identity == null)
        {
            _principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        }
        _applicationName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"];

        if (_principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!skipAuthorisation)
            {
                // set userRole cache name
                string userRoleCache = _principal.Identity.Name.Replace(DoubleSlash, string.Empty) + CacheSuffix;

                List<string> userRoles = GetUserRoles(_principal, userRoleCache);

                //get system defined Role groups
                List<string> restrictedRoleGroups = Roles.Split(_doubleBar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(r => r.Trim()).ToList();

                // iterate groups for authorisation 
                for (int i = 0; i < restrictedRoleGroups.Count(); i++)
                {
                    List<string> restrictedRoles = restrictedRoleGroups[i].Split(',').Select(r => r.Trim()).ToList();

                    List<string> matchingRoles = (from ur in userRoles
                                                  where (restrictedRoles.Any(mr => ur == mr))
                                                  select ur).ToList();

                    if (matchingRoles.Count().Equals(restrictedRoles.Count()))
                    {
                        _outcome = true;
                    }

                }
            }
            else { _outcome = true; }
        }

        if (_outcome == false)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Message/Index");
        }
}
```

Comment: A custom authorize attribute is not the right fit here. You're probably looking for policy auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @ChrisPratt The policy-based authorization framework doesn't support to enable custom action result return from the authentication handler. That's why I want to derive my own filter.

Comment: None of the authorization handlers do. That's what middleware like StatusCodePagesWithReExecute are for.